# Check if any of multiple values in a string is within a numerical range R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dummy data frame:

```
structure(list(ref = structure(1:7, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("gyrA", "parC"), class = "factor"), 
    result = structure(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("S479T", 
    "S83L", "S83L, D678E, D741E", "S83L, D87G", "T765E", "V196A, M248V, E678D"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
ref  gene  result
a    gyrA  S83L
b    gyrA  S83L, D87G
c    gyrA  V196A, M248V, E678D
d    gyrA  S83L
e    gyrA  S83L, D678E, D741E
f    parC  T765E
g    parC  S479T
```

What I want to do is to check if the numerical value in the column "result" (between the two letters in each entry) is within a specific range, specifically 67-106, but only when the column "gene" == gyrA. This needs to be checked for all numbers in each cell in the "result" column. 
The result in result_pos should return 1 if any of the numbers in the cell is within the specified range.
I tried the following:

```
df %>%
   mutate(gyrA_pos = ifelse(gene == "gyrA", gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", result), NA),
   result_pos = ifelse(gene == "gyrA" & gyrA_pos %in% as.character(seq(from = 67, to = 106)) == TRUE, 1, 0))
```

This works, but only for the entries with only one value. I also find it tedious to have to create a column with the letters stripped before matching. I want to end up with this:

```
ref  gene  result                 result_pos
a    gyrA  S83L                   1
b    gyrA  S83L, D87G             1
c    gyrA  V196A, M248V, E678D    0
d    gyrA  S83L                   1
e    gyrA  S83L, D678E, D741E     1
f    parC  T765E                  NA
g    parC  S479T                  NA
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make it clear, but do you also want to have `result_pos` show 2, 3 etc. if those are the ones that lie in the desired range? What should be returned if more than one `result` matches?

Comment: @CalumYou The result in result_pos should return 1 if any of the numbers in the cell is within the specified range. Sorry for not being clear, question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. You can use `str_extract_all` to get all the numbers in a `result`, not just the first, and then use `map` with `any` to check if any of the numbers are in the specified range. The end is just to insert `NA` where desired and convert to integers.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ref = structure(1:7, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("gyrA", "parC"), class = "factor"), result = structure(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("S479T", "S83L", "S83L, D678E, D741E", "S83L, D87G", "T765E", "V196A, M248V, E678D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df %>%
  mutate(
    result_pos = result %>%
      str_extract_all("\\d+") %>%
      map(as.integer) %>%
      map_lgl(~ any(.x >= 67L & .x <= 106L)),
    result_pos = if_else(gene != "gyrA", NA, result_pos),
    result_pos = as.integer(result_pos)
  )
#>   ref gene              result result_pos
#> 1   a gyrA                S83L          1
#> 2   b gyrA          S83L, D87G          1
#> 3   c gyrA V196A, M248V, E678D          0
#> 4   d gyrA                S83L          1
#> 5   e gyrA  S83L, D678E, D741E          1
#> 6   f parC               T765E         NA
#> 7   g parC               S479T         NA
```

Created on 2018-09-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! Simple and fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, `:=`(result = as.character(result), # coerce result to character
          result_pos = NA_integer_)] # set result_pos to NA 
DF[gene == 'gyrA', result_pos := {
  x <-
    lapply(strsplit(result, split = ","),
           gsub,
           pattern = "\\D+",
           replacement = "")
  as.integer(sapply(x, function(i)
    any(as.numeric(i) >= 67 & as.numeric(i) <= 106)))
}][]
#   ref gene              result result_pos
#1:   a gyrA                S83L          1
#2:   b gyrA          S83L, D87G          1
#3:   c gyrA V196A, M248V, E678D          0
#4:   d gyrA                S83L          1
#5:   e gyrA  S83L, D678E, D741E          1
#6:   f parC               T765E         NA
#7:   g parC               S479T         NA
```

The idea is to `strsplit` the column `result`, remove the letters, check for your condition and return as integer, only for the rows where `gene == 'gyrA'`.